# How to Send AT commands to Android phone?

Tags: android, bluetooth, at-command

I have 2 android phones connected with each other via Bluetooth and am able to communicate between them using the BluetoothChat example (using the input/output stream)

I am also able to make a Bluetooth connection between these phones using the `HandsFreeProfile` by using the following `UUID` for connection:

```
    private static final UUID MY_UUID = 
                  UUID.fromString("0000111F-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"); 
                  // UUID for Hands free profile
```

Now I want to send AT commands to one phone(Phone-B) from the other(Phone-A). I can send the command from phone-A to phone-B as String (using input/output streams) and receive it by the phone-B, but I do NOT know how to apply the incoming AT command on phone-B i.e. I don't know how to make phone-B do what AT command wants it to do.

I have read about the intent

```
android.bluetooth.BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_VENDOR_SPECIFIC_HEADSET_EVENT
```

but I'm not sure how to use this to send AT commands to the phone coz to use the intent some EXTRAS and a CATEGORY needs to be sent and I'm not sure what to send in those. For example below is the excerpt from the android website for the above intent:

*This intent will have 4 extras and 1 category.

> EXTRA_DEVICE - The remote Bluetooth Device
>   EXTRA_VENDOR_SPECIFIC_HEADSET_EVENT_CMD - The vendor specific command
>   EXTRA_VENDOR_SPECIFIC_HEADSET_EVENT_CMD_TYPE - The AT command type
>   which can be one of AT_CMD_TYPE_READ, AT_CMD_TYPE_TEST, or
>   AT_CMD_TYPE_SET, AT_CMD_TYPE_BASIC,AT_CMD_TYPE_ACTION.
>   EXTRA_VENDOR_SPECIFIC_HEADSET_EVENT_ARGS - Command arguments.*

I'll really appreciate if someone can help me out and tell me :

1. Can AT commands be reliably sent between 2 android phones in this way
2. Post some code to demonstrate how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

See my answer on this question:

[How to send AT commands based on BT Hands-Free profile in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610811/how-to-send-at-commands-based-on-bt-hands-free-profile-in-android/16854373#16854373)

Hope that was the answer you was after.