# Is there an AT command to direct audio (voice call) between two devices connected via Bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-sco

I have two devices connected via Bluetooth. Currently I am to initiate voice call from my device (programmatically from my app) to another device, after connecting to it using Handsfree Audio Gateway.

However, I am only able to initiate the call and not hear the other end or send my voice once the call is established. I realize that there is something more I must do for this. But I am unable to find out what it is. Perhaps there is an AT command for initiating call and routing audio to the Bluetooth connected handset? Or any other way?

My coding attempts so far are described here in this question : [How to initiate a call from HF through AG via Handfree Audio Gateway in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257916/how-to-initiate-a-call-from-hf-through-ag-via-handfree-audio-gateway-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

There is no AT command to start a SCO link (Audio link) over BT.

A SCO link is started in Android by using  [AudioManager.startBluetoothSco()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#startBluetoothSco%28%29)

Have not used this myself so I can't help you more about this.

Have you really connect a Bluetooth HF connection between two Android phones? I tought they only supported AG role not HF. It isn't a SPP connection you are using?

Comment: The phone, as I gather, supports only Handsfree Audio Gateway. So I connect using that, and then I am able to issue commands to it related to calls. But I am unable to route the audio of the call through Bluetooth

Comment: From what type of device do you connect towards your HF AG (phone)? Another Android phone?

Comment: How does your setup look like? 
Android phone acting as a HF-> issues a BT connection towards another android phone acting as HF AG? 
The phone that are AG. Does it say that it has a BT connection and are you able to connect audio towards the HF from its active call menu? If so, does the audio dis aper in AG device? If so, a SCO link is connected and you "only" need to route the audio on your HF device. If there is no possibility to transfer audio in your AG device you have not connected a correct HF link.

Comment: Yes, both AG and HF are android phones