# How to send AT commands to BT Headset

Tags: android, bluetooth, headset

I want to develop an application that controll BT headset, not manually.
For example, when I have incoming call, I want to send AT command to BT headset to reject or accept incoming call.
Here is my code to gain that goal.

Here is my code based on [How to send AT commands based on BT Hands-Free profile in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610811)

```
private UUID MY_UUID_SECURE = UUID.fromString("00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"); // It's my headset's uuid
...
tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID_SECURE); // Connect to my headset's profile(HSP)
...
// Here is rfcomm success
mmInStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();
mmOutStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
...
```

Connection is success and I can write any bytes to HSP.

```
mmOutStream.write("AT+CHUP\r".getBytes());
```

Above code is running correctly but my headset does not work on any commands.
What does it mean?
"AT+CHUP" is AT command to reject incoming call, isn't it?
But it does not work on my headset. Headset could not reject/accept incoming call now.
If anybody has expirences on that problem, please help me. I am also glad to see somebody's full source in github.
Please and thank you all.